# Run Code before view layer changes (during rendering)

Tags: scripting

Basically I'm writing an Addon that changes the materials of objects when switching ViewLayers. This already works when switching viewlayers in the UI (via msgbus):

```py
def on_view_layer_changed():
    ng = bpy.data.node_groups["lt switch"]
    ng.links.new(ng.nodes["Group Input"].outputs[bpy.context.view_layer.name], ng.nodes["Group Output"].inputs[0])
    print(bpy.context.view_layer.name)

def subscribe():
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=(bpy.types.Window, "view_layer"),
        owner=bpy,
        args=(),  # Optional arguments
        notify=on_view_layer_changed)
```

But of course this doesn't work when I hit render and all viewlayers are rendered. I need to be able to run code inbetween the individual viewlayer renderings. Does anyone have an Idea how to do this?

what it does:
[image]

Comment: I don't think so.  I believe that the various render engines don't expose that state change anywhere that's accessible to bpy